# Joomla Retrieve current route in module

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

This is something I feel should be easy, but after an hour so far scouring the web it just does not seem to be jumping out.

What I want is to have a module trigger a task in a component, then redirect to the last page.

To do this I want to get the current route in the modules form. However I cannot find any Joomla function that can output the current pages "JRoute", if I try use JRoute with no parameters it just outputs the url with no query, so will every method of JURI.

There must be an obvious answer to this, however for some reason I might just not be searching for the right thing and not turning up any results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
JURI::getInstance()->toString()
```

This will give you the current url.